# how to remove border-spacing gaps from zebra stripes

Tags: html, css, zebra-striping

I have a table that has both border-spacing and zebra striping. But when border-spacing and zebra striping are combined, the combination results in gaps between the columns rather than a smooth stripe. For example, in the table below there is an unsightly gap between Peach and Yes.

[image]

How can I keep the border-spacing, but remove those gaps in the zebra stripes?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bridgeland/xCBR9/

CSS:

```
table {
   border-spacing: 15px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #c4d8fd;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xCBR9/5/)

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table td { padding:10px 0; }
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #c4d8fd;   
}
```

Set a `padding` on the table cells, and use `border-collapse:collapse` on the table itself to remove the extra border.

Answer (score 1):

Use padding instead of `border-spacing`.

```
td,th{
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

This way you only set top/bottom padding, not left/right.

http://jsfiddle.net/xCBR9/4/

Answer (score 1):

don't add the `border-spacing: 15px;` to the `table`, add the spacing to `td`, or `tr`

such as here http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/Rzsvm/

Answer (score 1):

add spacing in your td:

```
table {
 border-spacing: 0px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #c4d8fd;   
}
td{
    padding:0 15px 0 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8MfB/